# Logger dependency injection, getting calling class name and source file path

Tags: c#, unit-testing, logging, dependency-injection

In a WinForms app, there is `Logger` class that is a form designed for logging, so that any class can call it.

There is a static `Configuration` class, inside which a `Logger` lives.

**Previous implementation**

Various classes would call the logger like so:

```
public class ImportController
{
    public void import()
    {
        try
        {
            // do the work...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Configuration.logger.log("Something failed");
            Configuration.logger.log(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current implementation**

The logger implements the following interface, which was extracted from it as part of refactoring to enable unit testing calling classes through dependency injection:

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void (string message, [CallerMemberName] string member = "", [CallerLineNumberAttribute] int lineNumber = -1, string fileName = "");
    void (Exception ex, [CallerMemberName] string member = "", [CallerLineNumberAttribute] int lineNumber = -1, string fileName = "");
}
```

As can be seen, the idea is to have it automatically log the calling class name and source file path.

The following is an example of an attempt to inject a logger into all classes that use it, in this instance the `ImportController` from above:

```
public class ImportControllerLogger
{
    public void log(string message, [CallerMemberName] string member = "", [CallerLineNumber] int line_num = -1, string filename = "")
    {
        Configuration.log.log(string message, "ImportController", lineNumber, @"Controllers\ImportController.cs");
    }

    public void log(Exception exception, [CallerMemberName] string member = "", [CallerLineNumber] int line_num = -1, string filename = "")
    {
        Configuration.log.log(exception, "ImportController", lineNumber, @"Controllers\ImportController.cs");
    }
}

public class ImportController
{
    ILogger _logger;

    public ImportController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public void import()
    {
        try
        {
            // do the work...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.log("Something failed");
            _logger.log(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**Questions**

Is this the correct approach to decouple the logger from all classes that use it?

It seems it might be better to create a *single* "LoggerHelper" class, that abstracts away the logger so that any class can make a call to it, instead of creating such a class for every calling class. How can the *name of the calling class* and *source file path for the calling class* be logged, in a proper way, without resorting to manually specifying it for each class? It worked in the previous implementation with the attributes.

Comment: Burn that code and use an established logging Framework. All of which I know support dependency injection.

Comment: @Fildor if it were up to me, I'd use NLog. I'd use a similar pattern though. However, unfortunately I'm not allowed to change that in this project.

Comment: BTW the interface lacks methodnames and ImportControllerLogger does not implement it.

Comment: @Fildor fixed the mistake you pointed out in the code snippet.

Comment: _"I'm not allowed to change that in this project"_ - sad to hear that. I won't start on a rant about "no 3rd party"-Seniors, though. OK, let's help you get this straight. But: Maybe it's worthwhile to have a look at the APIs of NLog (if that's you would prefer) and see if you can come up with something similar. I mean, they should have reasons to do things the way they do, right? Basically, there are the interface `ILogger<T>`, the Logger itself `Logger<T>` which can be created by `LogManager.CreateLogger<T>()` ... and then there's DI support, which I would have to look into, too.

Comment: @Fildor can I use something like `GetType` on the parameter T? To be able to get the class name?

Comment: Maybe just make a little dummy project and play around. That's the best way to figure out how you want to do it and what's actually possible to do. Man, I really do not envy you. Creating a logging framework is not as easy as it may sound. I wish you all the luck.

Comment: Please follow [naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had to implement something like that.
The code is simplified.

- ILogger

```
public interface ILogger
{
    event EventHandler<LogEventArgs> OnLogAdded;

    Type Type { get; }

    void Log(string message);
}
```

- Logger

```
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    public Type Type { get; }

    public Logger(Type type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public event EventHandler<LogEventArgs> OnLogAdded;

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        EventHandler<LogEventArgs> handler = OnLogAdded;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new LogEventArgs(message));
    }
}
```

- LogProvider

```
public static class LogProvider 
{
    private static List<ILogger> loggers = new List<ILogger>();

    public static ILogger CreateLogger<T>()
    {
        if (loggers.Select(x => x.Type.Equals(typeof(T))).Count() > 0)
        {
            throw new Exception($"There is allready a logger for the type {typeof(T)}");
        }
        ILogger logger = new Logger(typeof(T));
        logger.OnLogAdded += OnLogAdded;
        loggers.Add(logger);
        return logger;
     }

    private static void OnLogAdded(object sender, LogEventArgs e)
    {
        //add log to your config
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
public class SampleView
{
    private ILogger logger = LogProvider.CreateLogger<SampleView>();

    public SampleView()
    {
        logger.Log("TestLog");
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best implementation, but it works like a charm.